# What is $\arctan (9)$ in terms of $\pi$?

Tags: trigonometry

What is the pi fraction of $\arctan (9)$?  I converted it to degrees and decimal, but how is it expressed in terms of $\pi$?

Comment: `ArcTan[9.]/Pi`  returns `0.464777` in Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you for responding. That's in decimal though

Comment: Putting aside that it looks like a math question, not a Mathematica one, it's unclear what you mean by when you say "not a decimal" and "in terms of $\pi$". I guess you want to express it in a specific form. What constructs do you allow in that form?  Radicals of rationals?  If yes, why do you believe that $\arctan(9)$ is even expressible this way?

Comment: @Szabolcs Converting it to rad, it returns 1.46 rad, or 83.66 degree. I do not know if it can be expressed using π but I thought I might ask. The question is can it be written as something like π/3, 2π/5, etc. I think π/3 is 60 degrees, can we figure it out given its degree of 83.66?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you seem to want it in the form $a\pi$, but there is the *implicit* assumption in your question that $a$ must have a certain form. Make this explicit. You gave examples like $a=1/3$. I guess you're fine with any rational. What about $a=\sqrt{2}$? Is that acceptable? What about $a = \sin(2)$?  What about $a = e$ or $a = \int_1^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx$?  Even if you post on Math.SE, you should explain in precise terms what you mean when you say "express it in terms of $\pi$".

Comment: Here is what I am trying to simplify: 1/72 tan^-1 (9). I just need to "convert" the decimal into a pi fraction IF possible.

Comment: I doubt `ArcTan[9]/Pi` would be even algebraic, not to say rational number. Various expansions given by WolframAlpha would point to the direction it would be a transcendental number: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan(9)%2Fpi

Comment: Got it. Thank you all for taking the time to clarify!

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{1}{\pi}\,\arctan(9)$ is not a rational number, so your question makes little sense.

**Proof**. If we assume $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(9)\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have that $\frac{1+9i}{\sqrt{82}}$ is a $m$-th root of unity for some $m$.
The minimal polynomial of $\frac{1+9i}{\sqrt{82}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by $41x^4+80 x^2+41$. This is not a monic polynomial, hence it cannot be a cyclotomic polynomial. We reached a contradiction.

On the other hand, since the continued fraction of $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(9)$ is
$$[0; 2, 6, 1, 1, 2, 16, 9, 7, 5, 1, 7, 54, 26, 9, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2,\ldots]$$
we have the approximate identity $\arctan(9)\approx \frac{1677401}{3609047}\pi$.

Now we may prove that $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(9)$ is a trascendental number by invoking the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem). We already have that $\frac{1}{\pi i}\log\left(\frac{1+9i}{1-9i}\right)$ is an irrational number. If we assume it is an algebraic number, by GS we have that
$$ (-1)^{\frac{1}{\pi i}\log\left(\frac{1+9i}{1-9i}\right)} = \frac{1+9i}{1-9i}$$
is trascendental, contradiction.

Comment: It is not a rational number, I thought I was missing something, thank you!!

Comment: Sadly Mathematica is not willing to tell this straight away: `Simplify@Element[ArcTan[9]/Pi, Rationals]` stays unevaluated, which could indicate Mma doesn't know if it's rational or not.

Comment: @kirma: why *sadly*? We *proved* $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(9)\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ and we should be happy to still be slicker than machines :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Frankly I didn't notice this question has migrated from Mma.SE to Mathematics...

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate it using [`RootApproximant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html)

```
at92 = (ArcTan[9]/π // RootApproximant[#, 2] &) π

(* ((89579 + Sqrt[12802312961]) π)/436180 *)
```

The relative error is

```
(at92 - ArcTan[9])/ArcTan[9] // N

(* 1.52071*10^-16 *)
```

For a simpler, less accurate approximation

```
at91 = (ArcTan[9]/π // RootApproximant[#, 1] &) π

(* (1677401 π)/3609047 *)
```

with relative error

```
(at91 - ArcTan[9])/ArcTan[9] // N

(* 3.04142*10^-15 *)
```

Or using [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

```
at9r = (ArcTan[9]/π // Rationalize[#, 10^-16] &) π

(* (85761483 π)/184521902 *)
```

with relative error

```
(at9r - ArcTan[9])/ArcTan[9] // N

(* -1.52071*10^-16 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

While `Rationalize[ArcTan[1]/\[Pi]]` gives $1/4$, `Rationalize[ArcTan[9]/\[Pi]]` gives $\arctan(9)/\pi$.

```
`N[ArcTan[9]/\[Pi], 60]`
```

> `0.464776712522722725577810346306513918765266462161294796367476`

It does not seem to be a rational number

Comment: I really appreciate everyone taking time to clarify, thank you!